# JQuery addClass affect once

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I want to animate my div tag when the button is pressed, by adding animate.css class by jquery, but this only works once and stops working each subsequent time the button is being pressed.
This is html code:

```
    <div id="note" class="">a</div>
    <button id="submit">submit</button>
```

and this is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#note').removeClass();
    $('#note').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    $('#note').html('some text');
});});
```

you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/Lgg9D/5/

how to animate div each time press button?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {        
    $('#note').removeClass();
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#note').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
      $('#note').html('some text');
    },1);        
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgg9D/11/).

Answer (score 2):

it just take a little time before classes are removed. you can add a little delay after removing classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#note').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#note').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');},50);

        $('#note').html('some text');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgg9D/13/

Comment: this is very similar to my answer which was added 4 mins ago.

Comment: you know I was working on fiddle I didn't see your answer. If I saw it specially with -1 I wouldn't add my answer

Comment: the answer was correct, the only problem is it's hard to explain why it works here, I doubt it's involved internally how JS works, such as at the time of calling `addClass` the current class has not actually been removed yet, so a delay of `1ms` will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just toggle the class, It handles the addition and removal alone

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#note').toggleClass('animated fadeInLeft');
        if($("#note").html() == 'a')
        {
        $('#note').html('some text');
        }
        else
        {
        $('#note').html('a');
        }
    });
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgg9D/15/)